# One CSV with field that delineates CRS for QGIS?

Tags: qgis, csv, clip

I have a CSV with points with X,y coordinates. One of the fields is "Horizontal Datum," which says what the projection is. Here is a sample of the sheet:

[image: csv file]

QGIS lets me import this csv file, but when I try to clip it into another layer, it says it has trouble with the CRS. Should I make this into multiple layers with different projections?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you will need a different layer per projection.  Each layer can only have one projection in QGIS and QGIS will reproject them together for display.

Answer (score 0):

Just to complement @NathanW's great answer, you could **split** the CSV into multiple CSVs where they each contain all features for every **unique** projection in your field.

You can do this by importing the CSV into QGIS and then from the toolbar:

*Vector > Data Management Tools > Split Vector Layer...*

Then choose your "Horizontal Datum" field and the output folder:

[image: Split Vector Layer interface]